# Segmentation fault (core dumped) al introducir args a un programa en C

Tags: c, ip, core

He hecho el siguiente programa en C que ejecutará un programa en Python que utilizará las IPs que se han definido previamente en este programa:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char command[200];
    char *ip_list = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
    ip_list[0] = '\0';
    if (argc > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            char ip[20];
            strcpy(ip, argv[i]);
            strcat(ip_list, "- ");
            strcat(ip_list, ip);
            strcat(ip_list, "\n");
        }
        printf("IPs a añadir al archivo ips.yaml:\n%s\n", ip_list);

        FILE *fp;
        char line[200];
        fp = fopen("/opt/host-status/scripts/config/ips.yaml", "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Error al abrir el archivo ips.yaml.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        char *file_content = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
        file_content[0] = '\0';
        while (fgets(line, 200, fp) != NULL) {
            strcat(file_content, line);
        }
        fclose(fp);

        char *ips_start = strstr(file_content, "ips:");
        char *ips_end = strstr(file_content, "storage:");
        ips_end[-2] = '\0';
        if (ips_start != NULL && ips_end != NULL) {
            char *new_content = malloc((strlen(file_content) + strlen(ip_list) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strncpy(new_content, file_content, ips_start - file_content + 5);
            new_content[ips_start - file_content + 5] = '\0';
            strcat(new_content, ip_list);
            strcat(new_content, ips_end);
            fp = fopen("/opt/host-status/scripts/config/ips.yaml", "w");
            if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("Error al abrir el archivo ips.yaml.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            fputs(new_content, fp);
            fclose(fp);
            free(new_content);
        } else {
            printf("No se encontró la sección 'ips:' en el archivo ips.yaml.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        free(file_content);
    } else {
        printf("No se han especificado IPs para añadir al archivo ips.yaml.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    sprintf(command, "python3 /opt/host-status/main.py '%s'", ip_list);
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que deberia añadir las IPs definidas al ejecutar el programa en el fichero especificado pero estoy recibiendo el error de Core Dumped. No he podido encontrar ninguna solución y se que no es porque excede el límite de carácteres.

$ ./host-status 192.168.0.1 127.0.0.1
IPs a añadir al archivo ips.yaml:

- 192.168.0.1
- 127.0.0.1

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Intentando encontrar el error solo he podido extraer esto:

(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1329: file host-status.c, line 5.
(gdb) run 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.1
Starting program: /home/jet/Documents/jobs/host-status/service/host-status 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.1

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=832, argv=0x34000000340) at host-status.c:5
5   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

El archivo "ips.yaml" es el siguiente:

```
ips:
  - 0.0.0.0
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 192.168.0.1
  - 8.8.8.8
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: @Mateo lo añado al post

Comment: Creé un archivo vacío, gracias igual.

Answer (score 1):

El problema podría estar en la declaración de la memoria para `ip_list` y `file_content`. Actualmente, estás declarando un tamaño fijo de 1000 caracteres para cada uno, pero si la longitud de las IPs supera ese tamaño, podría causar un desbordamiento de búfer, lo que podría resultar en un Segmentation Fault.

Una forma de solucionar esto sería asignar la memoria dinámicamente utilizando la función `malloc()` basada en la longitud de la cadena de entrada. Por ejemplo, en lugar de:

```
char *ip_list = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
```

Podrías hacer:

```
char *ip_list = malloc((strlen(argv[1])+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Lo mismo se aplicaría para `file_content`.

Además, estás usando `ips_end[-2]` para eliminar los dos últimos caracteres del contenido del archivo, pero esto podría causar un comportamiento impredecible si la cadena no tiene al menos dos caracteres. En su lugar, podrías usar la función `strncpy()` para copiar solo la parte necesaria del archivo en `new_content`.

Por último, es posible que debas agregar un carácter nulo al final de new_content después de concatenar todo.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema de Segmentation Fault que estás experimentando.

Comment: Al actualizar el programa de la manera que me has dicho me aparece este nuevo error:
host-status: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Asegúrate de [no utilizar ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462): está prohibido aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Al depurar con el ejemplo dado, se produce un error de lectura en la línea:

```
ips_end[-2] = '\0';
```

Si se imprime el puntero de `ips_end` se obtiene 0 (o NULL).

En la línea anterior se llama la función [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) que devuelve un puntero nulo si no encuentra la cadena a buscar.

Debes tener el cuidado de verificar que no sea nulo antes de desreferenciar el puntero.

También asegúrate de que la posición (-2 en este caso) sea válida.